# Is there any method to get TraceId of Zipkin in Java Code

Tags: java, spring-boot, zipkin

I want to retrieve the TraceId of Zipkin, is there any method to get it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If service 2 is getting traceId from service 1, you can take the traceId from requestHeader in your java code. Otherwise sleuth generate a new traceId in service 2.

To get the trace Id In java

```
    @Autowired
    private Tracer tracer;
```

Just do

```
    tracer.getCurrentSpan().traceIdString();
```

Comment: what about retrieving traceId from service1?

Comment: yeah..you are right , for more details https://blog.michaelstrasser.com/2017/07/using-sleuth-trace-id/

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can also get the x-b3-traceid header information from the request, I created a Util class for that -> https://gist.github.com/walterwhites/067dd635986e564aafdb5ac559073b0f

```
public final class DebugUtils {

    private static String PURPLE = "\033[0;35m";  // PURPLE
    private static String RED = "\u001B[31m";  // RED
    private static String RESET = "\u001B[0m";

    public static class ZipkinDebug {

        private static String url = "http://localhost:9411/zipkin/traces/";

        public static void displayTraceUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
            String traceId = request.getHeader("x-b3-traceid");
            System.out.println(PURPLE + "DebugUtils:ZipkinDebug -> " + url + traceId + RESET);
        }
    }

    public static class RequestInfo {

        public static void displayAllRequestHeaders(HttpServletRequest request) {
            Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
            System.out.println(RED + "DebugUtils:RequestInfo -> " + RESET);
            headerNames.asIterator().forEachRemaining(header -> {
                System.out.println("Header Name:" + header + "   " + "Header Value:" + request.getHeader(header));
            });
        }

        public static void displayRequestHeader(HttpServletRequest request, String headerName) {
            System.out.println(RED + "DebugUtils:RequestInfo -> Header Name:" + headerName + "   " + "Header Value:" + request.getHeader(headerName) + RESET);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your main class you just need to call

```
ZipkinDebug.displayTraceUrl(request);
```